# How do I print the words on a list that do not have the letter 'e'?

Tags: python, python-3.6

The code must print the words on a list that do not have the letter e. The list I'm using is on a seprate file called words.txt.  My code has some holes in it but I'm not sure where they are, because I am getting words that only contain the letter e. This is excersise 9.2 in the textbook Think Python.

Lines 2 to 6 is a code to read a word and return True of False if it has rhe letter e.  I was then required to modify it to complete the task.

```
fin = open('words.txt')
def has_no_e(word):
  if 'e' in word:
    return True
  else:
    return False
count = 0
for word in fin:
    word = word.strip()
    if has_no_e(word):
        count = +1
        print (word)
percent = (count / 113809.0) * 100
print(str(percent))
```

The code is supposed to print all the words on words.txt that do not have the letter e.

Comment: Your `has_no_e` function returns `True` if `'e' in word` is true.

Comment: `has_no_e` is probably too simply to even *be* a function; you're just adding overhead to your code for no real benefit, as `if has_no_e(word):` isn't any clearer than `if 'e' not in word:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code is correct

```
count = 0
fin   = open('words.txt', 'r') #Open the file for reading
words = fin.readlines()        #Read words from file
fin.close()                    #Close the file

for word in words:              
    word = word.strip()
    if not 'e' in word:        #If there is NO letter e in the word
        count = count + 1
        print(word)

percent = (count / 113809.0) * 100
print(str(percent))
```

By doing

```
if 'e' in word:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

You selected every word with letter 'e', not words without them.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you very much for the prompt response.

Comment: You're welcome!:) Tell me if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_no_e(word):
  if 'e' in word:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

This function does the opposite of its name.  It returns `True` if the word DOES have an 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works in the function.

```
if 'e' in word:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so: (for the first 10 words):

```
filename = '/etc/dictionaries-common/words'
words = [word for word in open(filename).read().split() 
         if 'e' not in word]
print(words[:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire file contents are being read into `word` here. The `for` loop in above code should be modified from

```py
for word in fin:
```

to

```py
for word in fin.read().split():
```

Also, in case `has_no_e()` should return `True` when word doesn't contain `e` then its implementation should have following line:

```py
    if 'e' in word:
```

replaced with

```py
    if 'e' not in word:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could solve this problem after getting the words into a list.

```
words = ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'a', 'short', 'sentence.']
words_without_e = [ word for word in words if 'e' not in word ]

print(words_without_e)
```